# Timeout because of multiple JOINs in SSIS

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, ssis

I have following SQL, which I'm trying to run in a SSIS package ADO.NET Source.

SQL:

```
select 
b.itemCode as nimike,
e.OrdCustNum as asiakas,
d.DlvCustNum as asiakas2,
b.qty as maara,
c.Price as m_hinta,
c.CostPrice as o_hinta,
d.SalesRep as kasittelija,
d.orderNum as tilausnro,
d.VatDate as tap_pvm,
c.stock as varasto,
'Delivery' as til_tyyppi
FROM 
"PUB"."DlvLine" b
JOIN "PUB"."slsLine" c
    ON 
        b.itemCode = c.itemCode 
        and b.OrderNum = c.orderNum 
JOIN "PUB"."invLine" d
    ON 
        b.itemCode = d.ItemCode
        and b.InvNum = d.InvNum
        and b.DlvNum = d.DlvNum
        and b.OrderNum  = d.orderNum
JOIN "PUB"."SlsOrder" e
ON
    c.OrderNum = e.OrderNum
WHERE 
d.VatDate > '2019-10-22'
and c.AllDelivered = '1'
```

Preview results in timeout after 30 seconds, error message:

```
ERROR [HYT00] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver]Timeout expired.
ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Query aborted on user request (7495)
```

I wonder if it's about multiple JOINs, if I remove the second JOIN clause the query runs fine. What are my options?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets filter the `invoice line` item first before joining to your main table. I'm sure you have multiple invoice line item per `order number,` since you are not displaying any `amount` or `qty`, lets add `distinct` invoice line instead.

```
select 
    b.itemCode as nimike,
    e.OrdCustNum as asiakas,
    d.DlvCustNum as asiakas2,
    b.qty as maara,
    c.Price as m_hinta,
    c.CostPrice as o_hinta,
    d.SalesRep as kasittelija,
    d.orderNum as tilausnro,
    d.VatDate as tap_pvm,
    c.stock as varasto,
    'Delivery' as til_tyyppi
FROM 
"PUB"."DlvLine" b
JOIN "PUB"."slsLine" c
    ON 
        b.itemCode = c.itemCode 
        and b.OrderNum = c.orderNum 
JOIN 
    (select distinct ItemCode, DlvCustNum, SalesRep, orderNum, VatDate, InvNum, DlvNum, orderNum
        from "PUB"."invLine" where VatDate > '2019-10-22') d
    ON 
        b.itemCode = d.ItemCode
        and b.InvNum = d.InvNum
        and b.DlvNum = d.DlvNum
        and b.OrderNum  = d.orderNum
JOIN "PUB"."SlsOrder" e ON
    c.OrderNum = e.OrderNum
and c.AllDelivered = '1'
```

Comment: I added  `ItemCode` in `select distinct` and now it's working! Great thing!